# Change the menu sidebar based on the menu item selected - Semantic UI & JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, semantic-markup

I'd like to use SemanticUI to display different sidebars based on selected menu

I've tried one way, but it doesn't seem to work. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXrNEW)

Here, i have 2 menu items for the sidebar, i need to show '`first_sidebar`' if i'm inside the menu '`First`', if i'm inside '`Second`', i need to show the '`second-sidebar`'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show and hide sidebar as an ordinary HTML element with jQuery, using `$("div.second_sidebar").hide()` and `$("div.first_sidebar").show()`.

But, since sidebars are Semantic UI element that you initialized with `.sidebar()` method, you should use this same method to show and hide sidebars, e.g.:

```
$("div.second_sidebar").sidebar('hide');
$("div.first_sidebar").sidebar('show');
```

Reference is here:
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/usage